# Can we use the "request" returnable property of SCIM attribute even in GET request?

Tags: rest, scim, scim2

The SCIM RFC 7643 section-7 describes the schema definitions, the "returned" expects one of the following as the value:-

1. always
2. never
3. default - The attribute is returned by default in all SCIM
   operation responses where attribute values are returned.  If
   the GET request "attributes" parameter is specified,
   attribute values are only returned if the attribute is named
   in the "attributes" parameter.
4. request - The attribute is returned in response to any PUT,
   POST, or PATCH operations if the attribute was specified by
   the client (for example, the attribute was modified).  The
   attribute is returned in a SCIM query operation only if
   specified in the "attributes" parameter.

My question is around "default" and "request" values.
I have use-case where the attribute should be returned in GET request, only if requested explicitly in query parameters using "attributes".
I see in the "request" property description that, the behavior I am expecting is only possible for "POST", "PATCH" AND "PUT". Can I use this even for GET?

References - [enter link description here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7643#section-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
In the description of "request" returned type, it mentions,

> The attribute is returned in a **SCIM query operation** only if specified
> in the "attributes" parameter.

SCIM Query operation includes both

- Querying resources using `GET /<Scim Resource>`
  (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#section-3.4.2.1)
- Querying resources using `POST /<Scim Resource>/.search` (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#section-3.4.3)

> The inclusion of "/.search" on the end of a valid SCIM endpoint SHALL
> be used to indicate that the HTTP POST verb is intended to be a query
> operation

So, If you have any attributes with "returned" characteristics = "request", those will be returned in your query operation's response only if you specify those in "attributes" in your scim resource query request.